# Populating <select> dropdown with one array

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a list of over 100 colors in seperate `<td>`s. Each `<td>` has a unique ID. I would like to use jQuery to find the ID's of every td and put it in an array. Then I would like to use that array and create something similar to the following:

```
<select>
    <option value="array[0]"> array[0]</option>
    <option value="array[1]"> array[1]</option>
    ...
</select>`
```

Every example I've looked at so far requires the coder to manually type out the array. I'm hoping to find something more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("td").get()
```

gets you an array with all the matched elements.
Then you can just traverse, for every element of array you build up your options string.
Something like this:

```
var s = "";
var elements = $("td").get();
for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    var el = elements[i];
    s+='<option value="'+el.id+'">'+el.id+'</option>'; 
}
```

If you have other tds on the page, do something like $("element#that-is-parent-to-needed-tds td");

Comment: This won't work. Don't use a `for..in` loop on an array. It doesn't do what you expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var $select = $('<select>');
$('#tableID td[id]').each(function(idx){
    $select.append('<option value="' + this.id + '"> ' + this.id + '</option>');
});
$select.appendTo('#someElement');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the array just for populating the drop down then you can bypass creating array.
Try this:

```
<table id="colorsTable">
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    .
    .
    .
    .
</table>

<select id="colorsList" name="colorsList">
    <option value="array[0]"> array[0]</option>     
    <option value="array[1]"> array[1]</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function populateDropDown()
    {
        var colorsList = $("#colorsList");
        $("#colorsTable td").each
        (
            function()
            {
                colorsList.append($("<option/>").val($(this).text()));
            }
        );
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var cells = $('table tr td');
var sel = $('<select>');

cells.each(function(cell) {
 var opt = document.createElement('option');
 opt.value = cell.id;
 opt.innerHTML = cell.id;
 sel.append(opt);
});
```